# Load a new vim buffer in the background

Tags: vim

Is there a way to load a new buffer in Vim without opening a new window or replacing the contents of the current window? I would like to silently load it so that I can then manipulate it with functions that take a buffer number as an argument.

Comment: @perreal hmm that works make it an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `badd` command. There is some information on [vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ), or vim `:help badd`.